# Display two dates in one gridview column, but hide second date if the same as the first date

Tags: gridview

I have a gridview column which displays two date values. I would like to hide the second value in cases where the two dates are the same.

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Date Range">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <%# string.Format("{0:dd MMM yyyy} {1:dd MMM yyyy}", Eval("From_Date") ,Eval("To_Date"))%>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Date Range">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <%# string.Format("{0:dd MMM yyyy}", Eval("From_Date")).Equals(string.Format("{0:dd MMM yyyy}" ,Eval("To_Date")))? string.Format("{0:dd MMM yyyy}", Eval("From_Date")) : string.Format("{0:dd MMM yyyy} {1:dd MMM yyyy}", Eval("From_Date") ,Eval("To_Date"))%>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Not sure I got all the parentesis right, but something like this might do the trick!

Comment: Thanks Robert. There were just some missing closing brackets the rest seems good. Although I get this error message : Cannot implicitly convert type string to bool. I know what the error means, but don't really understand what the problem is.

Comment: Added the missing parentesis, and citation chars

Comment: Glad to help you out!